# Mysql - UPDATE JOIN sets an unknown value "2147483647" to every entry

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I want to update a whole *table* `sav` where the *column* `phone` contains the `id` from a table `stock_phone`. I want to set the `sav.phone`column to the `stock_phone.imei` value, here is the query I tried:

```
UPDATE sav JOIN
       stock_phone 
       ON sav.phone = stock_phone.id
   SET sav.phone = stock_phone.imei;
```

But then the `sav.phone` value is set to `2147483647` for every row, and this value doesn't match with any `imei` value from `stock_phone`.
I search about how to `UPDATE` and `JOIN` but my syntax seems correct according to the questions I read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved it myself..
I'm trying to set a too big integer into an `INT(8)` field. The `2147483647` value means ***Incorrect Integer***, that's why the value isn't matching with one of my records.
Hope it will help some people.

Answer (score 2):

`2147483647` equals to `2^31-1` limit of [`INT(4)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html). [IMEI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Equipment_Identity#Structure_of_the_IMEI_and_IMEISV_(IMEI_software_version)) number (15 digits) are greater of this value.

Comment: Yes this is a type error, I did not think about that (shame on me: some devices have IMEIs containing letters !). Thanks !

Comment: For me, EMEI contains only digits (exactly 15, included last control digit)

Comment: I agree with you, but apparently some tablets have been saved with IMEI containing letters in the database. I guess that's what have been returned when scanned.

Answer (score 1):

I am curious if this returns the same results:

```
UPDATE sav s       
   SET s.phone = (SELECT sp.imei FROM stock_phone sp WHERE s.phone = sp.id);
```

I don't see a problem with updating the key used for the `JOIN`, but perhaps that is triggering some sort of bug.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this way too, thinking it could be more explicit but it still sets `2147483647` to every entry (I tried again with your query). I execute queries on **PHPMyAdmin** directly, if it matters.

Comment: Well I went to discover what's wrong, `2147483647` means *Incorrect Integer*, I'm trying to set a too big integer into an `INT(4)` field and that's what it returns.. Still, get my upvote, thanks !